# Primefaces/JSF - Disable button based on two conditions

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I would like to disable a button in primefaces in the case of any one of the conditions is met. 
For example:

I have the commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton value="Check"  actionListener="#{myBean.someMethod()}" 
                 disabled="#{myBean.contador1 eq 0} ">
```

It works ok. However, I want to check another condition to disable the button too.

```
disabled="#{myBean.contador2 eq 100} ">
```

If I try one of them separately, the button is disabled. However, when I try to join both conditions, none of them works. I’ve tried:

```
 disabled="#{myBean.contador1 eq 0} || #{myBean.contador2 eq 100} ">
 disabled="#{myBean.contador1 eq 0} or #{myBean.contador2 eq 100} ">
 disabled="#{myBean.contador1 eq 0} , #{myBean.contador2 eq 100} ">
 disabled="#{myBean.contador1 eq 0} #{myBean.contador2 eq 100} ">
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is the right syntax

```
disabled="#{myBean.contador1 eq 0 or myBean.contador2 eq 100} ">
```

You basically start EL expression (`#{}`) only once, no matter how many beans you are going to call inside it.